# Absolute top:0 bottom:0 not working inside table-cell in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Building off a previous questions of mine, I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sharf224/o8nmuxt6/)

It has two columns on top of one column in small views, and 3 columns in a row in other views. This works as expected. However, for the design aspect, I wanted space between the content blocks. To remedy this, I made an absolute positioned element inside the cells that would be sized accordingly to fill the space, but leave a gap. This works excellent in Chrome, however IE11, both desktop, windows 8 app, and windows phone all do not work as expected.

In IE11 the blocks will only expand to fit the content (even though the absolute blocks do not contain any content...) I assume this is because IE is taking into account the natural cell padding the browser adds to make the cells the same height. The kicker is: If you give the block a set height, and use `bottom:0` the block will stick right to the bottom of the cell.

Here's the fiddle HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell"><div class="back"></div>One Line</div>
    <div class="cell"><div class="back"></div>Two<br/>Lines</div>
    <div class="cell"><div class="back"></div>More<br/>Than two<br/>Lines</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
.back {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    background:#777;
    z-index:-10;
}
.cell:first-child .back {
    right:5px;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) .back {
    left:5px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .cell:last-child {
        display: table-caption;
        caption-side: bottom;
    }
}

@media (min-width:769px){
    .cell:last-child .back {
        left:5px;
    }
    .cell:nth-child(2) .back {
        right:5px;
    }
}
```

What css hacks/tricks could I use to make the behavior of IE mimic that of Chrome? I would rather not use javascript to solve this problem.

Comment: @user4749485 unfortunately, I don't know which content will be the largest, so I can't accurately populate that placeholder.

Comment: did you find any solution for that?

Comment: @Ahamed It's been a while, but I don't think I did. I believe I had to change my implementation.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Seems impossible to resolve. I also don't know the largest size of the content, so static heights aren't a a possibility for me. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using in this way

```
.back{min-height: 56px;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just sets a minimum amount. If one is taller than that predefined amount, my problem remains the same.

Comment: Is that one dynamic? Let me change it and let you know